# Combine two SQL query in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, I want to display the combined output of the below sql queries in a table using one while loop. I have a table called **participating_institutions** which holds unique code and names for all institutions. I also have **trades** table where each of the institutions can either be a buyer, a seller or both (Yes, an institution can do a trade for its two clients). With the help of good guys here, I was able to match each code in trades table with corresponding names in participating institution table using sql JOIN as indicated in the queries. The first query below will sum all the buy values for each firm and the second query will do same for their sales. However, the table I want to display will have the [Sum(buy_value) + Sum(sell_value)] for each firm in the while loop. How do I achieve this using either mysql or php.
Note: The trade table has two column in it for buy_firm_code and sell_firm_code. The records they hold is the same depending on which side of the trade a firm participated.
Below is what I have done so far.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","password","database");

$total_value = 0;
$buy_value = 0;
$sell_value = 0;
$firm_name = "";
$institution_code = "";
$display = "";

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$buy_sql="SELECT p.institution_code, p.institution, SUM(t.trade_value)
value_bought FROM trades t JOIN participating_institutions p ON     p.institution_code = t.buy_firm_code GROUP BY t.buy_firm_code ORDER BY value_bought DESC";

if ($buy_result = mysqli_query($con, $buy_sql))
{
// Fetch one and one row for buy side
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($buy_result)) { 
    $buy_value .= $row['value_bought'].'<br>';
    $institution_code .= $row['institution_code'].'<br>'; 
    $firm_name .= $row['institution'].'<br>'; 

}

}

$sell_sql = "SELECT  p.institution_code, p.institution, SUM(t.trade_value) value_sold FROM trades t JOIN participating_institutions p ON p.institution_code = t.sell_firm_code GROUP BY t.sell_firm_code ORDER BY value_sold DESC";

if ($sell_result = mysqli_query($con, $sell_sql))
{
// Fetch one and one row for sale side
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sell_result)) {
    $sell_value.= $row['value_sold'].'<br>';
    $institution_code .= $row['institution_code'].'<br>'; 
    $firm_name.= $row['institution'].'<br>';

}

}
$total_value = $buy_value + $sell_value;
$display .= '<table><tr><td>'.$institution_code.'</td><td>'.$firm_name .'</td><td>'.$total_value.'</td></tr></table>';
echo $display;

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($buy_result);
mysqli_free_result($sell_result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I run this two problems:

1. The firms repeat, I guess because I am running two queries. What I
   want is one output record for each firm.
2. I don't get the overall total for each firm rather I get the sum of total buy and total sell of the first record

instead of

```
Firmcode A:  FirmName A: 20,000 
Firmcode B:  FirmName B: 40,000
Firmcode C:  FirmName C: 50,000
```

I get this

```
Firmcode A:  FirmName A: 
Firmcode B:  FirmName B:    20,000
Firmcode C:  FirmName C:
```

Comment: May i suggest you apply Divide and Conquer aproach. You work on the MySQL part and try to create a SQL that works then write the PHP. Also if you create a fiddle like this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/077e1/32) will be easier for us understand the problem and help you solve it. Otherwise readding so much code will take long time and discourage other to help

Comment: 1 issue I see is that you are concatenating your `$row['value_bought']` -> `$buy_value .= $row['value_bought'].'<br>';` && `$row['value_sold']` -> `$sell_value.= $row['value_sold'].'<br>';` which turns them into strings. So when you try to do you `$total_value = $buy_value + $sell_value;` you are trying to add strings, not integers.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have been able to resolve the issue. here is what I did. I created two views in my database with the below codes.  _SELECT p.institution_code, p.institution, SUM(t.trade_value)
value_bought FROM trades t JOIN participating_institutions p ON     p.institution_code = t.buy_firm_code GROUP BY t.buy_firm_code ORDER BY value_bought DESC_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. I have been able to resolve the issue. I created two views in my database using the two queries above. I then used a third query in my code to  join the two views  using the SUM aggregate function for my total buy and total sell values. It works perfectly now. Thanks for all your contribution.